# My tcp client using spring integration not able to get response

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have created tcp client using spring integration I am able to receive  response for my send message . But when I uses  localDateTime.now() to log time I am not able to receive the response of send message . I know this can be solved using time setting to make thread wait. As I am new to spring integration So kindly help me how to do it.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Test
{

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    // **************** Client **********************************************
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel()
    {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sendChannel()
    {
        MessageChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        return directChannel;
    }

    @EnableIntegration
    @IntegrationComponentScan
    @Configuration
    public static class config
    {
        @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sendChannel", defaultReplyChannel = "replyChannel")
        public interface Gateway
        {

            String Send(String in);

        }
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory()
    {
        AbstractClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost",
                9999);
        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new UCCXImprovedSerializer());
        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new UCCXImprovedSerializer());
        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);

        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setMapper(new TcpMessageMapper());
        return tcpNetClientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendChannel")
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway()
    {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(tcpNetClientConnectionFactory());
        tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // new LegaServer();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
        String temp = applicationContext.getBean(Gateway.class).Send("kksingh");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now()+"output" + temp);

        applicationContext.stop();

    }
}
```

My custom serialzer and deserialser UCCXImprovedSerializerclass
after updating as per @Garry

```
 public class UCCXImprovedSerializer implements Serializer<String>, Deserializer<String>
{
     @Override
    public String deserialize(InputStream initialStream) throws IOException
    {

        System.out.println("deserialzier called");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(initialStream)))
        {
            for (int c; (c = rdr.read()) != -1;)
            {
                sb.append((char) c);

            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String msg, OutputStream os) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(msg + "---serialize---" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "");
        os.write(msg.getBytes());
    }
   }
```

My server at port 9999 code

```
   try
        {
            clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
            System.out.println("client connection established..");
            is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            String tempString = "kksingh";
            byte[] tempStringByte = tempString.getBytes();
            byte[] temp = new byte[tempString.getBytes().length];
            while (true)
            {
                is.read(temp);
                System.out.println(new String(temp) + "--received msg is--- " + LocalDateTime.now());
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + "sending value");
                os.write(tempStringByte);
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

My log file for tcp client

```
2017-06-04 23:10:14.771  INFO 15568 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@1f12e153
kksingh---serialize---main
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
2017-06-04 23:10:14.812 ERROR 15568 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway          : Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for localhost:9999:57622:bc98ee29-8957-47bd-bd8a-f734c3ec3f9d
2017-06-04T23:10:14.809output
2017-06-04 23:10:14.821  INFO 15568 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
```

My log file for server side

```
client connection established..
kksingh--received msg is--- 2017-06-04T23:10:14.899
2017-06-04T23:10:14.899sending value
```

when I removed the localdatetime.now() from server and tcpclient  I am able to get response as outputkksingh

```
o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2017-06-05 12:46:32.494  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-06-05 12:46:32.495  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2017-06-05 12:46:32.746  INFO 29076 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-05 12:46:32.753  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.samples.tcpclientserver.Test       : Started Test in 2.422 seconds (JVM running for 2.716)
2017-06-05 12:46:32.761  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'replyChannel' channel
2017-06-05 12:46:32.762  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application.replyChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2017-06-05 12:46:32.763  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@1f12e153
kksingh---serialize---main
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----kksingh
outputkksingh
2017-06-05 12:46:32.837  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2017-06-05 12:46:32.839  INFO 29076 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'replyChannel' channel
2017-06-05 12:46:32.839  INFO 29076 --- [
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deserializer is deserializing multiple packets...

```
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
pool-1-thread-1---deserialize----
```

Which produces 4 reply messsages; the gateway can only handle one reply which is why you see that ERROR message.

You deserializer needs to be smarter than just capturing "available" bytes. You need something in the message to indicate the end of the data (or close the socket to indicate the end).

Comment: In my use case Message not have any character at the end to mark the stream end . So I closed the socket.But I am still getting same thing.Please if you can give example how I can make my deserializer  smatter .

Comment: Garry when i removed the localdatetime.now() from server and client .then I am able to see the response on my client side . logs are updated in the post

Comment: It might affect the timing - you can't assume all the data will arrive in one read - you have to keep reading until `-1` is received (indicating the end of the stream).

Comment: @Garry I have another concern related to the same. If my server maintain the session.Then I want my client not to close the connection after receiving the reply from the server.Or should not start a new connection after for sending  new message to server.
If u can suggest  the configuration changes or provide the link for the same

Comment: `tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(false);`, but you will need logic in the deserializer to know what the end of each message is.

Comment: ok garry but I have a concern that sometimes i don't receive the -1 unit in input stream instead I get the socket close exception.It will be great if you can suggest any  work around this .

Comment: Garry I also  have raised consequent  question kindly suggest approach
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551952/how-to-make-tcp-client-which-send-request-and-receive-response-also-accepts-the

Comment: If you get an exception, it probably means the server reset the connection (abnormal close).